# Power loss through a medium

Tags: rf, antenna

Say I amt transmitting an RF signal from an antenna through a non-freespace medium (e.g. sand, water, cement) how can I go about calculating the absorption losses up to a certain depth level? I feel like this should be a fairly common and well-known equation, but I cannot seem to find it.
Thanks all.

EDIT: For simplicity's sake I am assuming the wave is only traveling through a single medium, meaning reflection is not a concern.

Comment: Search for "Skin effect" formulae for loss vs frequency, depth and conductivity. Also, you really need to know the conductivity of the medium in question.

Comment: FYI, depending on the frequency, you might have worry about scattering as well.

Comment: When a radio signal is traveling through free-space and it encounters a change in media, you also need to worry about reflection, not just absorption in the new media. Just something to be aware of. Also, when you say "cement," I am guessing you mean "concrete." If the concrete is reinforced with steel bar, as most structural concrete is, it will probably act as a very strong screen for the RF radiation (depending on details of wavelength, etc).

Comment: Googlle "RF absorption" and find a table which deals with your proposed frequency and medium. Then do the math.

Comment: The lower the frequency the better - you should be able to find an answer I made on this very subject somewhere lurking in EE. Here is one link: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/174075/rf-communication/174087#174087

Comment: Here's another question I answered on the subject: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/163576/shallow-underwater-wireless-sensor-network/163583#163583

Comment: I have a lot of experience with the losses caused by all sorts of building materials including, wooden walls, brick walls, cement floors/ceilings, and the human body for medical implant devices. My advice is to measure it at the frequency of interest.

Comment: You need to know the material's complex permitivity i.e. its loss tangent.  Also, you can't just embed an antenna that was designed for use in free space - it won't have the same characteristic impedance and will not function effectively.